# Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS does not find micro SD card

Tags: micro-sd, mmc

- SanDisk micro sd card 32gb
- Transcend MicroSD card reader
- Ubuntu 16.04.2

During an install of [motioneyeos](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki/Installation) I noticed that the `/dev/mmcblk*` are not there.  I checked `lsusb -a` and see that the card reader is being detected:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 8564:4000 Transcend Information, Inc. RDF8
```

I checked `dmesg` and see:

`dmesg | grep sdb`

```
[    4.277771] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 62333952 512-byte logical blocks:(31.9GB/29.7 GiB)
[    4.278644] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    4.278647] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[    4.279518] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    4.283747]  sdb:
[    4.286514] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1753.658942] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 62333952 512-byte logical blocks: (31.9 GB/29.7 GiB)
[ 1753.659708] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1753.659711] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 1753.660468] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1753.664577]  sdb:
[ 1753.667208] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

The output of the `lspci` command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Crystal Well DRAM Controller (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0d22 (rev 08)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Crystal Well HD Audio Controller (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

I also checked the kernel `.config` (I am using 4.4.0-78-generic) and see the following:

```
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK=m
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_MINORS=8
CONFIG_MMC_BLOCK_BOUNCE=y
CONFIG_SDIO_UART=m
CONFIG_MMC_SDHCI=m
```

Strange thing is that the card reader is being looked at as `/dev/sdb`.  For example the output of the `udisksctl status` command:

```
TS-RDF5 SD  Transcend     TS37      000000000039         sdb
```

`fdisk -lu` output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 29.7 GiB, 31914983424 bytes, 62333952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x197087fd
```

Strange that the Disklabel type is "dos"?

I have also modprobe'd the following modules:

```
modprobe mmc_core
modprobe mmc_block
modprobe sdhci
```

I unplugged the card and re-plugged it in and see the following in `dmesg`:

```
[ 6442.411915] usb 4-6: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 6442.430868] usb 4-6: New USB device found, idVendor=8564, idProduct=4000
[ 6442.430870] usb 4-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 6442.430872] usb 4-6: Product: Transcend
[ 6442.430873] usb 4-6: Manufacturer: TS-RDF5 
[ 6442.430874] usb 4-6: SerialNumber: 000000000039
[ 6442.433246] usb-storage 4-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6442.433355] scsi host7: usb-storage 4-6:1.0
[ 6442.611492] usb 4-6: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 6442.851860] usb 4-6: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 6442.870833] usb 4-6: New USB device found, idVendor=8564, idProduct=4000
[ 6442.870835] usb 4-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 6442.870837] usb 4-6: Product: Transcend
[ 6442.870838] usb 4-6: Manufacturer: TS-RDF5 
[ 6442.870839] usb 4-6: SerialNumber: 000000000039
```

Anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write the image to the SD card using Etcher.  I am now able to boot the motioneyeos image.